# Office365 EWS error: EWS not available because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request

Tags: powershell, office365, exchangewebservices

Trying to delete folders in user's archives.

The code has worked for some mailboxes, does not work for others.  I do note some of the mailboxes are unlicensed, would that cause the below issue?

Failure:

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "FindFolders" with "3" argument(s): "Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request."
```

My code has been built thanks to some stuff i've found on here already, such as doing the remove/add of the xanchor header.  But still throws error. Powershell Code

```
    Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList Exchange2013_SP1
    $service.Credentials = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials -ArgumentList "$uu","$pw"
    $service.Url= new-object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
    $service.Timeout = 600000
    $service.HttpHeaders.Remove("X-AnchorMailbox")
    $service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox","$MailboxName")

    $FolderName = "xxx"

    $service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress,$MailboxName)
    $oFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)

    $oFolderView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep

    $oSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$FolderName)
    $oFindFolderResults = $null
    $oFindFolderResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::ArchiveMsgFolderRoot,$oSearchFilter,$oFolderView)

    $oFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$oFindFolderResults.Folders[0].Id)

    $oFolder.Delete([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::HardDelete)
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue when I run SyncFolderHierarchy for certain Archive Mailboxes. Most of the online forums have "setting X-AnchorMailbox header" as the solution, but my code has this header set for years now and this error is happening for the past month.

Comment: check if sign-in is enabled for the respective user mailbox, enabling the sign-in fixed my issue